# Batch copy files to new directories that match the file name

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have 250.000 files all in one directory.
The files are all in the format

```
1a.jpg  
1b.jpg  
1c.jpg
```

... and goes up to      1f.jpg then the number is incremented by one

```
2a.jpg  
2a.jpg  
2c.jpg
```

... and so on.

Now I want to copy all files that start with 1 to a new directory called 1,
all files that start with 2 to directory 2 and so on.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this "old fashioned" .BAT Batch file if you wish:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
   set dir=%%~Nf
   set dir=!dir:~0,-1!
   if not exist !dir! md !dir!
   copy %%f !dir!   
)
```

Copy this Batch file to the directory where the files resides and execute it. It will create the new directories in the same level, but you may easily modify this.

Answer (score 3):

Group all the files by the first character and then copy each group to the destination folder:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | Group-Object {$_.Name[0]} | Foreach-Object { $_.Group | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\test\$($_.Name)" }
```

EDIT: this should perform faster:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | Copy-Item -Destination { "C:\test\$($_.Name[0])" }
```

Comment: c:\test is where all the destination folders should exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 250,000 files in one directory name ***n***[a-f].jpg, I would expect ***n*** goes from 1 to 41,667 and you want to have 41,667 directories each having 6 JPG files. If that is the case, here is my solution, a little more involved:

- First, it strips the letter (a-f) and the extension .jpg from the
  item's FullName to get the destination folder.
- Next it checks if the destination folder exists, if it does not it is
  created.
- Finally, the item is copied to the destination folder.

  ```
  Get-ChildItem *.jpg | ForEach-Object {
   $destination = $_.FullName -replace '[a-f]\.jpg'
   if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType directory
   }
   Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 dir -filter *.jpg | % { Copy-Item -PATH $_ -DESTINATION .\$($_.BaseName.ToCharArray()[0]) }
```

In this way the destination folders MUST exist!

Comment: I created some directories 1,2 and 3 but nothing happens when I run the command